# Why would os.nice(10) fail on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, nice

Why would `os.nice(10)` fail with `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted` on OS X? Running from a standard user account:

```
$ python
…
>>> os.nice(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Details:

- Python 2.7.2
- OS X 10.8.4

Comment: Maybe the process is already running with a higher nice level. Check with `ps` to see what `nice` level your process is running with.

Comment: Ah, that's it! I forgot that I'd nice'd down the terminal a couple of days ago, and didn't realize it was an error to nice up past 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Lukas Graf, `os.nice` increments the nice level, rather than setting it.

This appears to instead be an OS X bug, which is triggered if you call `nice` while sitting at a nice priority of 20 or higher:

```
nice -n 20 python -c 'import os; os.nice(10)'
```

fails, while

```
nice -n 19 python -c 'import os; os.nice(10)'
```

works. A simple C program exhibits the same problem:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    if(nice(10) < 0)
        perror("nice");
}
```

prints an error if you run it as `nice -n 20 ./test`, but succeeds if it is run as `nice -n 19 ./test`.

---

The reason is because a nice level of 20 is above the maximum nice level supported by the `nice` API (`NZERO`). OS X's `nice` utility uses `setpriority` so it ignores the limit, but the `nice` C function (which is used directly by Python) does care. If the process priority is 20 or above, `nice` will attempt to set the priority to 19 which is not allowed (since it would increase the process priority, which only a privileged user can do).

This is a weird bug, but it can easily be avoided by never using a process priority of 20.

Comment: Err, disregard the previous comment. Python's behavior is correct. It is just an error to nice up past 20.

Comment: @nneonneo sorry, I deleted my comment because after writing it, I observed behavior that seems to contradict it: With my `python` starting at nice `0`, I can call `os.nice(10)` repeatedly, and it never errors, always increments by a relative amount, and caps at `19`. However, a single `os.nice(-1)` always results in `Operation not permitted`, irrespective of any preconditions.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Yeah, that's because `os.nice(-1)` is asking for an "increment" of -1, which by definition would decrease the niceness.

Comment: @nneonneo yeah, but shouldn't I be allowed to do that for my own processes?

Comment: (I don't completely remember your comment, but I do remember that it pointed out that `os.nice` was an increment, a detail that I completely overlooked.)

Comment: @LukasGraf: no, that would allow a nobody user to make his processes high-priority. Processes aren't permitted to raise their own priority unless they are privileged (i.e. are running as root).

Answer (score 1):

Check what your PRIO_MAX is and which nicenesses are allowed to be used by non super-users

Users other than the super-user may only alter the priority of processes they own, and can only mono-tonically monotonically tonically increase their ``nice value'' within the range 0 to PRIO_MAX (20).

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/renice.8.html